# C++ polymorphism lost through C callback

Tags: c++, c, callback, polymorphism

*Note: constuctors/destructors and includes have been ommitted in the code snippets below for the sake of clarity.*

I'm using a library in which a function `registerCallback` expects the following arguments:

- a C-style function pointer to register the callback
- a `void*` 'user_data' to transmit whatever one sees fit

Since I'm coding in C++ and I want my callback to call a class member method, which I cannot directly do due to the C-styling of the `registerCallback` first argument, I have writen this function:

```
extern C {
    void handler( void* userData ) {
        (static_cast<Base*>(userData))->handle();
    }
}
```

And I use the `registerCallback` function as follows:

```
class Base {
    public void handle() {}
};
...
Base b;
registerCallback( handler, &b );
```

This works well so far.

Now, let's add a bit of complexity:

`Base` class has a pure virtual function `toto` called by `handle()` and I have `Child1` and `Child2` classes that extends `Base`.

```
class Base {
    public:
        void handle() { toto(); }
        virtual void toto() = 0;
};
class Child1: public Base {
    public: virtual void toto() { cout << "CHILD 1" << endl; }
};
class Child2: public Base {
    public: virtual void toto() { cout << "CHILD 2" << endl; }
};
...
Child1 c;
registerCallback( handler, &c ); // --> seg fault!!
```

And here is the problem: since in the extern-C function, I cast `userData` to `Base*`, the call to `toto` in `handle()` refers to a hypothetic `Base::toto()` method, which causes a seg fault when the callback is triggered.

If on the other hand I do not cast to `Base*`, I get a `‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type` compiler error.

How could I keep the actual type of my variables from being stripped off by the passing through the callback?

**Edit**

Here is the stacktrace from GDB:

```
Stacktrace:
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7bce41d in Base::handle ...
#2  0x00007ffff7bce110 in handler ...
```

And back up in the C `handler` function:

```
(gdb) p (static_cast<Base*>(userData))->handle
Cannot take address of method handle
```

Comment: Neither `Child1` nor `Child2` is derived from `Base`.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. We really need to see the *actual* inheritance tree, as well as the `registerCallback` function and how you actually call it.

Comment: I guess this *is* the actual inheritance tree, and that's the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Once you do make `Child1` and `Child2` inherit from `Base`, you will also need to `static_cast` to `Base*` when you pass the pointer to `registerCallback` (i.e. `registerCallback(handler, static_cast<Base*>(&c))`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The function pointer passed to `registerCallback` is `&handler`, not `&Base::handle`.  `handler` (note the R) is a non-member function.

Comment: I've corrected the question to add inheritance from Base for Child1/Child2.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, that's takes care of that problem. To the OP: Thinking about your naming-strategy might be a good idea. Readability, and maintainability, should be a very high priority. If you come back to the code in a couple of years time, would you still remember the difference and know what happens with such similar names?

Comment: As for the "corrections", is it part of the *actual* code, or something you added because of the comments and answers? Because if you modified the code after the answers and comments, that makes the current comments and answers, as well as the question itself, basically worthless.

Comment: I came here from the close vote review queue. I don't understand how this question got there. I find it perfectly okay, albeit a bit confused (the author got the cause of the problem wrong). Could those voting for closure perhaps re-consider and rescind their vote?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my code do have a correct inheritance tree, but the code is way more complex that what I tried to show here (hence the mistakes in the process). I'm currently coding what is explained in answers below and will come back with a feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> since in the extern-C function, I cast `userData` to `Base*`, the call to `toto` in `handle()` refers to a hypothetic `Base::toto()` method

That shouldn't be an issue. Because `toto` is virtual, even when it's called from a non-virtual member function of `Base`, it should dispatch to the final overrider in the dynamic type of the object.

However your code cannot be guaranteed to work in the current form because you are converting `Child1*` directly to `void*` when you pass `&c` to `registerCallback`. This means that that `void*` value will point to the first byte of the `Child1` object. When that pointer is converted to `Base*` in `handler`, the resulting value will also point to the first byte of the `Child1` object---not necessarily to the first byte of the `Base` subobject of the `Child1` object.

In order to ensure that you have the latter, you need to cast `&c` to `Base*` *before* passing it to `registerCallback`. This ensures that the pointer value will be adjusted to point to the first byte of the `Base*` subobject of the `Child1` object. Then that pointer will round-trip through `void*` and everything should work.

(This is in addition to what was pointed out in the comments---that you may have forgotten to make `Child1` and `Child2` derived from `Base`.)

Comment: precisely the problem, which I was explaining at the same time.  Only one mistake with your answer -- he needs to cast the pointer before the conversion **to** `void*` takes place, that's `registerCallback` not `handler` (which casts **from** `void*`)

Comment: @BenVoigt oops, yeah, that's what I meant. I'll fix it.

Comment: Well, that was clearly an error in my code, but unfortunately correcting it was not enough to solve the issue. I've added the stacktrace (GDB) in the initial question in case that might ring a bell to someone.

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer since this is clearly what is wrong with the example I wrote, even if my code still seg fault (probably for yet another reason).

Answer (score 3):

You can implicitly convert a derived object pointer to a base pointer.  Just because you don't have to write any code, does not mean there is no conversion.

When you `static_cast` between related types, the compiler will do the appropriate adjustments to the pointer.  When you `static_cast` from `void*`, there will never be any adjustment at all.  The pointer must have originally come from the exact (modulo *cv-qualification*) pointer type.  Having a related type is not sufficient.

In particular, this sequence is trouble:

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

Derived d;
Base* pb = &d; // ok
void* pv = &d;  // legal but wrong
Base* pb2 = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(pv);  // legal but wrong
```

After this sequence, `pb2` doesn't point to the `Base` subobject of `d`, it points to the beginning of `d`.  What you must do instead is convert the same pointer type to `void*` that you will later retrieve:

```
Derived d;
Base* pb = &d; // ok
void* pv = pd;  // pointer to subobject
Base* pb2 = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(pv);  // correct!
```

In your code, this means that you must cast `&c` to `Base*` before calling `registerCallback`.

Comment: `void my_register(Base& base) { registerCallback(handler, &base); }` and then `Derived d; my_register(d);` to avoid explicit cast.

Comment: @Jarod42: Eww, taking address-of a parameter passed in by reference and keeping the pointer beyond the function return.  While I like doing implicit conversion rather than a cast, there are cleaner ways than that.